# singularity column width without floating

Tags: singularitygs

I've 12 columns grid setup using singularity. Many times I'm looking for a simple variable of column width. I can use grid-span(), but it involves margins and floats. 
Is there any mixin/function which will return only column width in %? 
I'm searching for this for two days without any success. I found only span-columns(x, y); but it does not work.

Thanks for pointing to a direction.

EDIT: **solution found**

It was my mistake trying to use column-span (https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Grid-Helpers#column-span) as a mixin with `@include`. Correct use is for example:

```
width: column-span(2, 6); //width will be set to 2 columns at six position.
```

Comment: Thanks @andrey-lolmaus-mikhaylov for pointing this out. I'm still new to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution found**

It was my mistake trying to use column-span (https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Grid-Helpers#column-span) as a mixin with @include. Correct use is for example:

`width: column-span(2, 6);` //width will be set to 2 columns at six position.